# WordPress code works on function.php but not as an independent plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have create a piece of code that uses a plugins API to display some information related to that plugin.
and when I used that piece of code on function.php it worked
but when I have removed it from function.php and past it to a new plugin for just the propose of holding that code, it didn't work. and it keeps saying "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class"

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was that some of the classes were not declared yet when the plugin started to try to access them, while when I used function.php the all the classes were declared by then. because wordpress runs function.php after it runs all of the other plugins. and to solve that I used add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'myfunction', 100 );